# How can I read the first message from the second email address?

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I have the following email address in my outlook (local) and would like to read (for example) the first message from the second email address. How can I solve it?

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

# all Email Adress in Outlook:


for account in mapi.Accounts:
    print(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
    print("###########################################################################")
```

```
test1@outlook.com
test2@gmail.com
test3@gmail.com
###########################################################################
```

Comment: "first" as seen in Outlook? Or first meaning the latest? In the Inbox folder? Or elsewhere?

Comment: I mean, the first message in inbox from the second email. also first message in inbox from test2@gmail.com

Comment: "first" message assumes the items are sorted in some manner. They won't be unless you explicitly call `Items.Sort` specifying a particular property and the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [NameSpace.Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property which returns a [Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.stores) collection object that represents all the Store objects in the current profile. The following VBA code sample shows how to iterate over all stores and folders in Outlook:

```vb
Sub EnumerateFoldersInStores()
 Dim colStores As Outlook.Stores
 Dim oStore As Outlook.Store 
 Dim oRoot As Outlook.Folder 
 
 On Error Resume Next 

 Set colStores = Application.Session.Stores 
 For Each oStore In colStores 
   Set oRoot = oStore.GetRootFolder 
   Debug.Print (oRoot.FolderPath) 
   EnumerateFolders oRoot 
 Next 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub EnumerateFolders(ByVal oFolder As Outlook.Folder) 
 Dim folders As Outlook.folders 
 Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim foldercount As Integer 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 
 Set folders = oFolder.folders 
 foldercount = folders.Count 
 'Check if there are any folders below oFolder 
 If foldercount Then 
   For Each Folder In folders 
     Debug.Print (Folder.FolderPath) 
     EnumerateFolders Folder 
   Next 
 End If 
End Sub
```

The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages, so you may find all the required properties and methods form the sample.

The [Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store) object provides the [GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

To get the first item from the folder you need to sort the Items collection using the [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) method which sorts the collection of items by the specified property. The index for the collection is reset to 1 upon completion of this method. The name of the property by which to sort should be enclosed in brackets, for example, "[RecievedDate]".